# Fingerprint Issue on Ubuntu 20.04 lock screen

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I have configured the fingerprint in my Ubuntu 20.04 and rebooted the system. But still, I am not able to unlock the system with my fingerprint. Nothing happens when I touch the fingerprint image on the fingerprint. I have attached a snapshot of the configuration.

Fingerprint enabled:

[image: Fingerprint enabled]

Configured:

[image: configued]

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Thinkpad T490. I know I previously hat Ubuntu 20.04 on this computer and unlocking with fingerprint worked. Did you find the solution in the meantime?

Comment: Not Yet! Let me know how you fixed it So I can configure it in my Dell Vostro 15 3510 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it's now working.
For some reason I had to enroll two fingers and then use only one particular finger to unlock.

1. Enroll two fingers either in the GUI in Settings/Users or with `fprintd-enroll`. For example, left index and right index finger.
2. Run `fprintd-verify` to find out which finger is required. The output should look like this:

> ```
> andrej@notas:~$ fprintd-verify
> Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
> Listing enrolled fingers:
>  - #0: left-index-finger
>  - #1: right-index-finger
> Verify started!
> Verifying: left-index-finger
> Verify result: verify-match (done)
> ```

3. If the result from above is `verify-match`, try if you can use the above mentioned finger in the Ubuntu Lock screen or Login – it should work.
4. If you prefer to use another finger for unlocking, you may have to reset and enroll again, while using right index finger as the left one.